# Android Wear Offline use of Audible?

Tags: android-wear, audiobooks

Is there a way to sync Audible audiobooks to Android Wear for offline use in a similar manner to how I can sync Google Play music?  I would like to be able to listen to a book while out for a morning jog without toting my phone along.

Answer (score 1):

I've asked Audible and they said their app is not available in Android Wear yet, but encouraged me to submit feedback requesting support for it. Which I did.